# How to approach long texts in key names for i18next?

Tags: localization, internationalization, translation, i18next, react-i18next

When localizing content with i18next, what is the key:value naming approach suggested for long paragraphs of text? I've only seen examples with short strings in the documentation and examples, where the entrie string becomes the key name.

For Paragraphed text like below do you assign nicknames to each paragraph for namespacing?

ex:

```js
en: {
   about: {
     title: "A word from the President",
     "Président du Conseil d’Administration et co-fondateur": "Chairman of the Board of Directors and co-founder",
     "p1": "<pretend this is english...>Comme nous aurions aimé être à l’origine de cette citation qui illustre avec tant de profondeur ....",
     "p2": "<pretend this is english...>Parce que notre technologie a une portée bien plus large que le sport de haut niveau, elle"
     ...
  }  
}
```

```html
<h1 className='equipe-category'>
        <span>Le mot du Président</span>
      </h1>
      <p>Le Mot de Laurence Besse<br/>
        Président du Conseil d’Administration et co-fondateur</p>
      <blockquote>
        <p>«&nbsp;Mens sana in corpore sano&nbsp;»</p>
      </blockquote>
      <p>Comme nous aurions aimé être à l’origine de cette citation qui illustre avec tant de profondeur et justesse l’ambition fédératrice des co-fondateurs de notre start-up. Femme et Hommes de convictions, nous avons toujours recherché l’excellence et essayé de relever des défis. Notre rêve serait que notre technologie inCORPUS® soit adoptée par tous les acteurs de la vie économique, au sein de toutes les institutions, des grandes, moyennes et petites entreprises mais aussi enseignée à chaque écolier à travers le monde, afin que dès le plus jeune âge chacun puisse devenir responsable et acteur de sa propre santé.</p>
      <p>Parce que notre technologie a une portée bien plus large que le sport de haut niveau, elle peut avoir de manière plus globale des impacts positifs sur toutes les activités humaines, dans la vie personnelle comme professionnelle de chacun. Nos quotidiens nous soumettent à des stress multi factoriels et génèrent de la Fatigue. Stress et Fatigue engendrent des baisses de forme, mal êtres et maladies qui ont des conséquences sur la qualité comme la durée de nos vies. inCORPUS® est l’outil qui peut nous aider à prendre en charge notre santé : il nous permet d’évaluer en instantanée notre état de forme, anticiper nos risques de burn out et propose des solutions pour retrouver une bonne forme physiologique. Grâce à inCORPUS®, il est à la portée de chacun d’entre nous de prendre conscience que l’on peut soi-même changer les choses et agir.</p>
      <p>Nous avons une équipe formidable, engagée autour d’un projet fédérateur qui a un sens pour chaque être humain. J’ai beaucoup de chance d’être au cœur de cette aventure humaine et je profite de ces quelques mots pour souligner ici combien la confiance de notre investisseur a été décisive, il est à la source d’inCORPUS® et nous ne l’oublions pas. Chacun de nos collaborateurs œuvre dans l’intérêt général, je ne doute pas que nos efforts collectifs porteront leurs fruits au-delà de nos inspirations individuelles, le collectif est notre plus grande force.</p>
      <p>Ma quête d’absolu m’a poussée à franchir parmi les plus hauts sommets du monde, tester mes limites dans l’apprentissage de l’humilité parce que la Haute Montagne nous enseigne à comprendre et accepter les lois de la nature. Aux côtés d’alpinistes chevronnés, j’ai beaucoup appris sur moi et compris que ma motivation, mon principal moteur était de servir en contribuant, par mon action, à améliorer le bien-être de tous.</p>
      <p>J’aimerais terminer ce mot en invoquant la mémoire du Dr Emmanuel Cauchy disparu prématurément en montagne en 2018. Co-fondateur de be.care S.A, il était à nos côtés depuis le premier jour. Précurseur en Médecine d’urgence de haute montagne, celui qu’on appelait affectueusement « Le docteur vertical » manque à toute notre équipe, il demeurera à jamais dans l’ADN d’inCORPUS®.</p>
...
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If the long text will never have any moving parts, just dump the whole thing in there. If it will be changing at some point, make interpolation somewhere in the middle of the string.

I do not have an i18n next example for that one but a regular vue i18n one.
https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/interpolation.html#slots-syntax-usage